# I'm unable to get the selected data from spinner when I'm using arraylist tospinner

Tags: java, android, arraylist, spinner

I'm unable to get the selected data from spinner when I'm using arraylist to spinner.

Here when I'm using array of fixed length then it sets the spinner's selected data to textview but when I'm using arraylist then it's not getting set.

```
public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    int i=0;
    String data;
    String[] array;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        // data = strings[0];
        arrayList.clear();
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(strings[0]);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                long c=dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                int count = (int)c;
                array= new String[count];

                Iterator iterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 = (DataSnapshot) iterator.next();
                    // array[i] = dataSnapshot1.getValue().toString();
                    // i++;
                    arrayList.add(dataSnapshot1.getValue().toString());
                }
                Toast.makeText(Register_Activity.this,"Now Select : "/*+array[0]*/, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        // super.onPostExecute(s);

        switch(n){
            case 0:
                adapter[0] = new ArrayAdapter(Register_Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array);
                spinner[0].setAdapter(adapter[0]);
                break;
            case 1:
                adapter[1] = new ArrayAdapter(Register_Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array);
                spinner[1].setAdapter(adapter[1]);
                break;
            case 2:
                adapter[2] = new ArrayAdapter(Register_Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array);
                spinner[2].setAdapter(adapter[2]);
                break;
            case 3:
                adapter[3] = new ArrayAdapter(Register_Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array);
                spinner[3].setAdapter(adapter[3]);
                break;
        }

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                spinner[n].setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        // data = spinner[n].getSelectedItem().toString();
                        data = spinner[n].getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                        Toast.makeText(Register_Activity.this, "hey"+data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register_Activity.this);
                        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure: "+data);
                        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                **textViews[n].setText(data);
                                spinner[n].setEnabled(false);**
                                n++;
                                if (n < 4) {
                                    new GetData().execute(data);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                return;
                            }
                        });

                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }, 300);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an inner class? I see you're switching on 'n' but I don't see where it is defined.

Comment: yes It is an inner class and it's calling by it's object with an argument in a particular method.